# Passing a class from one controller to another controller in Java fxml

Tags: java, fxml

I am trying to get a specific class to be defined in another controller, but only then do I stop with the following errors:

Java.lang.reflect.Invocation TargetException
Java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Private void BtnEditar(){
     Produto produto = TbPRodutos.getSelectionModel.getSelectedItem();
     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLoader();
     loader.setLocation(FXMLEditarProdutoController.class.getResourse("/view/FXMLEditarPrdoutoController.fxml"));
     FXMLEditarProdutoController controller = loader.getController();
     controller.setProduto(produto);
}
```

Comment: Can you once try using the absolute path?It might be that there is some relative path issue.

Comment: It would help if you posted the stacktrace for the exception.